# j2me emulator error

Tags: java-me, emulation

I am using kemulator to run j2me game (my own developed) when I try to run it i get an error which says "can not find MIDlet class plz check jad or use -midlet param"

Classpath

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <classpath>
     <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
     <classpathentry kind="src" path="res"/>
     <classpathentry kind="con" path="J2MELIB"/>
     <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
         </classpath>
```

There is a package org/rhynn/ and there`s no such thing as a src folder in myGame.jar. I am using Eclipse ME to export this game.

actually there is no res or src folders in that jar. PS : I`m new at those Manifest and other (except Java ME) so I don`t know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

A j2me application or game must have at least one class that extends [`MIDlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html). Take this class full name, for example, org.rhynn.MyGameMIDlet and pass it to -midlet param.

Comment: And how about exporting this game ? When i export and i check that jar file what`s inside i can see that 2 folders are missing (src and res folders)

Comment: all .java files inside src folder are compiled and a corresponding .class file is created inside the jar file. All files inside res folder are copied to the jar file.

Comment: thanks for you`re help. I am using now net Beans for better exporting jar

Answer (score 0):

try using [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/) to pack jar file